# how to store serial data sent by arduino as buffer and print in processing?

Tags: arduino, processing

I have written a code in arduino which sends string of data
 Arduino code lines:

```
 int analog_value = analogRead(A0);//reading forward voltage
  int analog_valuer = analogRead(A1);//reading reverse voltage
 fwd_voltage = (analog_value * 5.0) / 1024.0; 
  rev_voltage = (analog_valuer * 5.0) / 1024.0;
 fpower =  ((fwd_voltage)*(fwd_voltage)*10000);
rpower = ((rev_voltage)*(rev_voltage)*10000);
String fp = String(fpower);
String rp =String(rpower);

 Serial.println("REV");
 Serial.println(rp);
Serial.println("W \n");
Serial.println("FWD");

 Serial.println(fp);
 Serial.println("W");
```

I want to print the data in processing console like this

> REV [some value] W
>
> FWD [some value] W

This is my processing code

```
void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
while(port.available()>0){
val = port.readString();
 }
if (val!=null)
{
 println(val);

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the [Processing Serial library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/) and the [serialEvent()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/serialEvent_.html) example. This shows you how to buffer a string of characters until the LineFeed(`\n`) character is received.

From there you should able to parse (trim, split, etc.) the string received over serial and extract the `rp`/`fp` values as needed.

Comment: :I'll try. and do i need to change the way i write serial.println function in arduino for my desired output shown in question?

Comment: It totally depends on what you need out of that output. Currently, yes it looks like you do need to change the calls in Arduino if you want `REV [some value] W` to be output for example to something like: ```Serial.print("REV");
 Serial.print(rp);
Serial.println("W \n");``` (e.g. output a new line only when you need it). Give it a go, it might not be as complex as you think :)

Comment: OK thanks. also  I've seen the examples you suggested. I'll just try .